# Balinese Hinduism symbology

Tags: identification-request, symbols

I am looking for the meaning of the following symbols that I found on my last trip to Bali:

[image: Image with symbol in Balinese]

Could anyone help me with that?

Well, in fact I'm only seeking for the meaning of this one:

[[image: Cropped part of the image]]

Comment: Those symbols seem to be balinese script. If you haven't already, you should also ask in balinese/Indonesian online forums/groups. There are 1 billion Hindus worldwide but only 4 million of them are balinese.